# How to use jar files which has java files?

Tags: java, javafx, jar

I want to create JavaFX application, also I have "executable jar file" in this "jar" there are java files(in this java files all functionality of application), I want to use this java files and its methods in javaFX application, how can I do it?

*Image of java file which in the JAR and I want use start() method in javaFX application* :
[image]

Comment: JARs don't usually contain Java files. They contain compiled classes. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use methods from decompiled .class java files from JAR and use in javaFx app.

Comment: How would you use any other java file? Also, you can use them without even decompiling. Just put the jar in your classpath.

Comment: You cant call decompiled source codes. The Java VM needs compiled code (class files).

Comment: look image which I am attached, this peace of code from JAR, my aim here to use start() method in JavaFX Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most IDE's have their own process of adding external code to your project.  On top of that there are programs that deal specifically with the build logic of your project.. e.g gradle/maven.  Which IDE are you using and are you using a build system to assemble your project?

In gradle you can specify a dependency using it's maven coordinates.

```
dependency {
    group: 'org.myOrg', name: 'thecore-code', version: '2.0'
}
```

In maven it's xml.  Here's an example I grabbed from mvnrepository.com

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-cypher-runtime-util -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-runtime-util</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In intellij idea you can add external libraries to your module. Using these steps.

1. File>ProjectStructure

[image]

2. Click the plus icon and navigate to the location where your JavaFX jar is

[image]

Comment: I added jar file how u said, but I do not how to use methods from java file which is in jar

Comment: I done it and transformed jar file now I want to use methods from java files which is located in jar